# I want to use my other class includes listener on my main class / Java minecraft Paper plugin

Tags: java, class, plugins, listener, minecraft

- I use gradle for build, Java, minecraft, Paper plugin
- ctrl+f , figure out " the problem "

I made each of these plugins separately. Now, I am putting them together into one plugin but separating each class. Then, this error occurred. I want to solve this problem.
I thought `third_function.third_listener` could be used for that place, but It seems to be worng...

```
package com;

import net.kyori.adventure.text.Component;
import net.kyori.adventure.text.format.NamedTextColor;
import org.bukkit.GameRule;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;

import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;



public class mainclass extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().warning("Server started.");

        first_function first = new first_function(this);
        first.onEnable();

        second_function second = new second_function(this);
        second.onEnable();

        third_function third = new third_function(this);
        third.onEnable();
        PlayerJoinEvent third_listener;
        third.onPlayerJoin(third_function.third_listener); // the problem. please help me, how can I get rid of this error?

    }
}

class first_function implements Listener {

    private final mainclass plugin;

    first_function(mainclass plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    void onEnable() {
        this.plugin.getLogger().warning("Hello, world!");
    }
}

class second_function implements Listener {

    private final mainclass plugin;

    second_function(mainclass plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }
    void onEnable() {
        World world = this.plugin.getServer().getWorld("world");
        world.setGameRule(GameRule.DO_DAYLIGHT_CYCLE, false);
    }


}

class third_function implements Listener {

    private final mainclass plugin;

    third_function(mainclass plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }
    Listener third_listener = (this);

    void onEnable() {
        this.plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
    }

    @EventHandler
    void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        event.getPlayer().sendActionBar(Component.text("Welcome",(NamedTextColor.BLUE)));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should register the listener and not try to call the method yourself. For example:

```java
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    third_function third = new third_function(this);
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(third, this);
}
```

Also, I mostly suggest you to use global java names convention, such as name `ThirdFunction` instead of `third_function` for example